# Get handle of child of nativeElement

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular, and we are using angular 7. We have a button component, labeled as "Send Email" and when we click the button from the webpages where it is rendered, it opens up the default emailing window (example outlook/gmail etc) from where we can send an email.

My problem is I need a handle of the opened up emailing dialog/window to determine if the email was sent or was cancelled. Additionally, if I can retrieve info on to whom it was sent to and what was the subject line. Looks like my nativeElement's **type is "< a>"**.

Something similar code like :

```
aDialog= this.dialog.open(aDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
aDialog.afterClosed().subscribe((data: EmailInfo) => {
  if (! data) {
    // cancel button was clicked
    return;
  }
   this.to = data.to;
   this.from = data.from;
   this.subject = data.subject

   //Now log 
  });
});
```

Is there a way to get the handle  of that native email-dialog and the fields that I need to retrieve info from?

**Code snippets :**

1> email.link.component.ts :

notice : `@ViewChild("sendEmail") sendEmailButton: ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>` and `Onclick` method

```
@Component({
  selector: "lib-email-link",
  templateUrl: "./email.link.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./email.link.component.scss"]
})
export class EmailLinkComponent extends BaseComponent {
  private email: Email;
  @Input() from = "";
  @Input() to = "";
  @Input() tooltip = `Send email from this context (opens in default email client)`;
  @Input() pageContext: EmailPageContext = undefined;
  @ViewChild("sendEmail") sendEmailButton: ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>;
  mailToLink = "";

  constructor(private emailService: EmailService) {
    super();
  }


  onClick(): void {
    if (this.sendEmailButton) {
      this.sendEmailButton.nativeElement.click();
    }
  }
}
```

I tried by modifying as (did not work):

```
onClick(): void {
    if (this.sendEmailButton) {
      this.sendEmailButton.nativeElement.addEventListener("close", (data: any) => {
        console.log("========>" + JSON.stringify(data));
      });
      this.sendEmailButton.nativeElement.click();
    }
  }
```

2> email.link.component.html

```
<span>
  <!-- Default "Send Email" button -->
  <button
    type="button" class="default-content btn-with-right-icon"
    mat-stroked-button color="accent"
    [matTooltip]="tooltip" matTooltipPosition="after" matTooltipShowDelay="1000"
    (click)="onClick()">
    Send Email
    <mat-icon>launch</mat-icon>
  </button>
</span>
<a #sendEmail style="display: none;" [href]="mailToLink"> </a>
```

3>It's been used as (in parent html):

```
<lib-email-link #emailLink [pageContext]="PageEnum.context">
</lib-email-link>
```

Comment: can u solve with `Output()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: New Answer**

Ok, rereading what you actually want, the answer is basically you can't. There is no way to know if the e-mail was actually sent from the code. Unless you write the dialog yourself and send the email yourself.

Imagine what could happen if a site had access to the desktop outlook application. It could send e-mails in your name, read your inbox, etc.

you can read more about it here https://javascript.info/intro#what-can-t-in-browser-javascript-do

You can however log the to, from and subject that was sent to the mail client (but there is no guarantee that even that is going to be used)

**Old Answer**

Why do you need the button and the link?

Can't you just do something like:

```
<a #sendEmail (click)="doClickStuff()" [href]="mailToLink" class="default-content btn-with-right-icon"> Send Email
<mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></a>
```

This is my example running it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bytp4h

Comment: I need a notification that email was sent or the dialog was cancelled. And if possible the field values of to, from and subject

Comment: Is the parent on item 3 the component that has the field values? What I proposed here is to just combine that button and the link so you don't need to worry about doing extra clicks. If the parent is indeed the component with the field values you just need to use Output and emit that the button was clicked on the click event of the link itself. It's getting late here, but I will update the answer with how to do that in the morning.

Comment: What do you mean by "opens up the default emailing window"?

Comment: When I click the button, it will open the email composing dialog depending on user's default email client. For example if the default email client is outlook, then it will open email-composing dialog from outlook etc.

And it's just a button that already labeled as "send email". When I click that button, it will open up the email-composing-dialog based on default email client. I need to find out a way to confirm if the email was sent or was cancelled.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can't basically.